# Query GPS coordinates evenly distributed over area

Tags: sql, typescript, sqlite, gps, prisma

I have a dataset of mountain summits in the European alps that I want to visualise on a map. In order not to overcrowd the UI I query all summits in the the current view of the map, get the most prominent (by sorting them on elevation) and take a certain amount.

```js
await prisma.mountain.findMany({
    where: {
      lat: { gt: lat_min, lt: lat_max },
      lng: { gt: lng_min, lt: lng_max },
    },
    orderBy: {
      elevation: "desc",
    },
    take: 20,
  });
```

That works great as long as the map is fairly zoomed in but of course the results start to cluster in a specific region with higher mountains pretty fast as you zoom out.

How can I write a query that distributes the results more evenly over the queried area?

I tried to make the results more center focused by moving the bounds of my query more to the center as the user zooms out. But that didn't improve the results when zoomed out far.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current query query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dividing the area in into a grid and then querying all the summits  in each cell. That resulted in a pretty even distribution.

To prevent the summits from disappearing when the map is moved, I could also just divide the whole globe into cells and load all cells that are overlapping with the current bounds of the map.